# Update number of divs displayed based on a text input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

I think i am going in the right direction i just seem to be missing something simple

i am using the jquery knob plugin to update the input field

```
$('document').ready(function() {

    $(".knob").knob({
                    change : function (value) {
                        //console.log("change : " + value);
                    },
                    release : function (value) {
                        //console.log(this.$.attr('value'));
                        console.log("release : " + value);

                        var num = parseInt($("#sitesinput").val());
                        var total = $(".one").length;
                        alert(num + ' ' + total);

                              $(".one").slice(1,value).fadeToggle();


                    },
                    cancel : function () {
                        console.log("cancel : ", this);
                    }
                });

});
```

```
<div class="item box one">1</div>
<div class="item box one">2</div>
<div class="item box one">3</div>
<div class="item box one">4</div>
<div class="item box two"></div>
<div class="item box two"></div>
<div class="item box two"></div>
<div class="item box two"></div>
<div class="item box three"></div>
<div class="item box three"></div>
<div class="item box three"></div>
<div class="item box three"></div>
```

I have attached a link to the demo i have been working on [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jrand/HYt4Z/4/)

Thanks,

Comment: do you have a working example from another site?

Comment: No sorry this is something i have been working on i have not seen it done before

Comment: OK, I can see the demo, but I still do not understand what it is supposing to be doing?

Comment: As the number inscreases on the knob, hide the divs. as it goes down, show them. I think

Comment: as you adjust the value for the input using the dial it should show that many div's with a class of .one fading them in and out as you adjust it i intend to do this for the other sets as well allowing me to customize the content displayed like a filtering system.

Comment: Jeff Shaver - yeah that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the fade toggle to this:

```
$('.one').slice(0,value).fadeOut();
$('.one').slice(value).fadeIn();
```

That says to hide the ones that are below the value and show the ones that are above it. You were close, but the fade toggle was hiding/showing ones that you didn't want to.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HYt4Z/6/